# Call srand only once when loading perl modules

Tags: perl, random, perl-module, srand

My script is separated into multiple packages. `main.pl` loads `A.pm`, which loads `A::B.pm` and `A::C.pm`. They all use `rand`. However, if I specify a seed for `srand` in `main.pl`, the latter modules seem to generate their own seed anyway. How can I seed the RNG only once and have the entire script predictable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `srand` in a `BEGIN` block in `main.pl`, before loading `A`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
...

BEGIN { srand(7) }
use A;
...
```

---

A complete example:

`A.pm`:

```
package A;

use B;
use C;

CORE::say "A: ", rand();
```

`B.pm`:

```
package B;

CORE::say "B: ", rand();
```

`C.pm`:

```
package C;

CORE::say "C: ", rand();
```

`main.pl`:

```
BEGIN { srand(7) }

use A;

CORE::say "main: ", rand();
```

Running `perl -I . main.pl` always print:

```
B: 0.266444196765409
C: 0.682035230190621
A: 0.265490593427
main: 0.129110848853948
```

If I put `srand(7)` after `use A`, then the first three prints (from `A`, `B` and `C`) are randoms, and only the one in `main.pl` is always the same.

Comment: That is, if you want to use `srand`, you need to call it before your first call to `rand`. Otherwise, `rand` calls `srand` for you and `srand` chooses its own seed.